# Equation manipulation tips/explanation for $2v_1w_1v_2w_2=v_1^{\ \ 2}w_2^{\ \ 2}+v_2^{\ \ 2}w_1^{\ \ 2}$ and its solution of $\mathbf{w}=a\mathbf{v}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was hoping I could get some equation manipulation tips for finding a particular solution to the following equality:

> $2v_1w_1v_2w_2=v_1^{\ \ 2}w_2^{\ \ 2}+v_2^{\ \ 2}w_1^{\ \ 2}$

where $\mathbf{v}=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ and $\mathbf{w}=\langle w_1, w_2 \rangle$.

I know that the answers are:

> $\mathbf{v}=0$ or $\mathbf{w}=0$ or $\mathbf{w}=a\mathbf{v}$ for some scalar $a$

I can see that all of the proposed solutions work just fine, but if I had quickly scanned this equation, I would have only concluded that equality holds when $\mathbf{v}=0$ or $\mathbf{w}=0$.

How do I reformulate the equation so that the final proposed solution ($\mathbf{w}=a\mathbf{v}$ for some scalar $a$) becomes apparent?

---

Here is what I have so far:

$$2v_1w_1v_2w_2=v_1w_1v_2w_2+v_1w_1v_2w_2$$

and

$$v_1^{\ \ 2}w_2^{\ \ 2}+v_2^{\ \ 2}w_1^{\ \ 2}=v_1v_1w_2w_2+w_1w_1v_2v_2$$

Equating these:

$$v_1w_1v_2w_2+v_1w_1v_2w_2=v_1v_1w_2w_2+w_1w_1v_2v_2$$

The only trick I can think of to reveal the $\mathbf{w}=a\mathbf{v}$ structure is the following:

$$\color{red}{v_1w_1v_2w_2}+\color{blue}{v_1w_1v_2w_2}=\color{red}{v_1v_1w_2w_2}+\color{blue}{w_1w_1v_2v_2}$$

$$\color{red}{v_1w_1v_2w_2}-\color{red}{v_1v_1w_2w_2}= \color{blue}{w_1w_1v_2v_2}-\color{blue}{v_1w_1v_2w_2}$$

From here, assume that the red colored (or blue colored) expressions sums to $0$. For example:

$$\color{red}{v_1w_1v_2w_2}-\color{red}{v_1v_1w_2w_2}=0$$

$$v_1w_1v_2w_2=v_1v_1w_2w_2$$

$$\text{Canceling terms and rearranging}$$

$$\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{w_1}{w_2}$$

Working on the blue terms (still with the assumption that they sum to $0$) results in the same expression...so we effectively have $0=0$ and the requirements to arrive at that solution is the same for each side (i.e. $\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{w_1}{w_2}$)

I interpret the expression of $\frac{v_1}{v_2}=\frac{w_1}{w_2}$ as necessarily implying that $\mathbf{w}=a\mathbf{v}$ because of how fractions works...but I am not really certain what the constraint that the sum **equals zero** is really saying. If someone could lend some insight on this final point, it would be appreciated!

Comment: $(v_1 w_2 - v_2 w_1)^2 = v_1^2 w_2^2 - 2 v_1 v_2 w_1 w_2 + v_2^2 w_1^2$

Comment: @WillJagy ahhh. Thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2v_1w_1v_2w_2=v_1^2w_2^2+v_2^2w_1^2$$

$$(v_1w_2-v_2w_1)^2=0$$

Hence we have $$v_1w_2=v_2w_1$$ which is what you obtained.

The determinant of the matrix  $\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \\ w_1 & w_2\end{bmatrix}$ is $0$, hence the conclusion.

Note: Be careful when you divide by a number, we should check that it is non-zero.